# RIP Robert Hardy, Actor for Cornelius Fudge

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Robert Hardy, best known for his role as Cornelius Fudge in the Harry Potter movies has died at the age of 92.

Older viewers will also know him as Chancellor Griswold from the 10th Kingdom

[image]

And his iconic role in British TV's All Creatures Great and Small as hapless vet Siegfried Farnon

[image]

Comment: He was also [an Oxford student of both C.S. Lewis and J.R.R. Tolkien](https://heavy.com/news/2017/08/robert-hardy-dead-dies-harry-potter-actor/).

Comment: @ibid Thanks for that bit of trivia!

Comment: This is a good listen - http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b090004z